# Boolean operator which gives true from two similar values

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-logic

Given two boolean variables x and y, the operator should be such that

```
boolean getResult(boolean x, boolean y) {
    return x op y;
}
```

the following assertions pass

```
assertEquals(getResult(true, true), true);
assertEquals(getResult(false, false), true);
assertEquals(getResult(true, false), false);
assertEquals(getResult(false, true), false);
```

Is there any operator for this?

**Edit.**

Sorry, I missed mentioning operator other than equality check. I'm looking for some kind of operation which can give a combined result like we have in general logical gates. I just want to know if its possible or not. If possible, whats the operation.

Comment: Im confused do you want it to return true or false randomly?

Comment: @Luke it's not random at all. Only returns `true` if both the parameters are the same and `false` if they aren't. Completely deterministic.

Comment: Yes. I think i missed saying other than equality check. Some kind of operation which can give a combined result like we have in general logical gates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any operator for this?

Yes, the operator for this can be `==`.

Check the explanation given below:

```
true == true => true
false == false => true
true == false => false
false == true => false
```

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getResult(true, true));
        System.out.println(getResult(false, false));
        System.out.println(getResult(true, false));
        System.out.println(getResult(false, true));
    }

    static boolean getResult(boolean x, boolean y) {
        return x == y;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
false
false
```

Alternatively, you can get the same result by negating `bitwise exclusive OR` operation as demonstrated below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getResult(true, true));
        System.out.println(getResult(false, false));
        System.out.println(getResult(true, false));
        System.out.println(getResult(false, true));
    }

    static boolean getResult(boolean x, boolean y) {
        return !(x ^ y);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
false
false
```

Comment: sorry but i have edited the post to include a missing detail.

Comment: @xploreraj - I've added an alternative way to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to check if the two values are equal.

```
boolean getResult(boolean x, boolean y) {
 return x === y;
}
```

Comment: sorry but i have edited the post to include a missing detail.

Comment: ok :) You can do it by using the alternative way mentioned in the @Arvind's answer